# turtlebot_interactive_markers

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to make the turtlebot_ineractive_markers and I cant. the error I get is:

In file included from /home/albert/ros_diamondback/interactive_markers/src/interactive_marker_server.cpp:32:0:  /home/albert/ros_diamondback/interactive_markers/include/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_server.h:35:56: fatal error: visualization_msgs/InteractiveMarkerUpdate.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Which means that I need to copy the interactive_marker_server.h to /home/albert/ros_diamondback/interactive_markers/include/interactive_markers/

The question is: where do I find this document?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11788/turtlebot_interactive_markers/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are using ROS Diamondback, however Interactive Markers is new in Electric -- you cannot build anything depending on interactive markers in diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2